# What Is the behavior of forkJoin when it is not In a SwitchMap/MergeMap in Epics

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I want to understand what happens when I directly pipe to an action$ and try to use forkJoin operator

```js
const action1 = { type: "ACTION_1" };
const action2 = { type: "ACTION_2" };
```

in a switchMap forkJoin works fine.

```js
export const testForkJoinSwitchMap: Epic<Action> = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(action1),
    switchMap(() =>
      forkJoin(
        from(fetch("https://api.github.com/users")).pipe(
          map((res: any) => {
            return res;
          })
        )
      )
    ),
    map((data: any) => {
      // do something with data
      return action2;
    })
  );
```

If I took it out of the switchMap then:

```js
export const testForkJoin: Epic<Action> = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(action1),
    forkJoin(from(fetch("https://api.github.com/users"))).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        return action2;
      })
    )
  );
```

I get the typing error:

```js
Argument of type 'Observable<{ type: string; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<{}, Action<any>>'.
```

I want to know why it does not compile? and the reason of the type mismatch, what makes the epics without the forkJoin invalid in this case?

edit: I know that forkJoin is not meaningful for a single observable, but I put 1 to keep the example smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`observable.pipe()` only takes **operators** inside it.

forkJoin is an operator which returns an **observable** that's why you get that error. `Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'` i.e forkJoin which returns an observable is not assignable to type of operator function.

switchMap, on the other hand, is an operator which returns an OperatorFunction and operates on an observable that's why your first approach worked. `switchMap(() => someObservable)` and `someObservable` in this case is `forkJoin()`

It's also evident from your imports. You might have imported forkJoin from `rxjs` library whereas switchMap from `rxjs/operators` library.

Comment: this makes sense to me, but per https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin, it says forkJoin is an operator, could it be that forkJoin is an operator but not a pipeable/lettable operator? I think 'from' and 'of' or anything that is imported from 'rxjs' and not from 'rxjs/operators' are that way too?

Comment: Oh yes. I should rephrase my answer that forkJoin is an operator which returns an Observable. So yes any operator for that matter imported from 'rxjs' must return an Observable although I am not sure. switchMap returns an OperatorFunction.